# write .log in excel load_workbook with python InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support .log file format, please

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, database

I'm trying to open up my log file then read from line to line and write it to an excel file that already have a template so i need to used `load_workbook`

```
import re
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import *

file = "cpcpk/1P00392G01_02.LOG"
file1 = 'cpcpk/1P00392G01_02 1x30times CpCpkReport.xlsx'

wb = load_workbook(file1)
ws = wb["1_BOARD_30X_CpCpk"]#sheet name

y = 5
x = 2
f = open(file, 'r')
for line in f:
    if re.match('^@', line):
        for line in f:
            if re.match('^\"', line):
                x += 1
                
            else:
                z = re.split('=|\(|,|\)', line) 
                
                if z[2] == '':
                    z[2] = '0'
                
                cel1 = ws.cell(y, 1)
                cel1.value = z[0]
                
                cel2 = ws.cell(y, x)
                cel2.value = z[1]
                
                cel3 = ws.cell(y, 35)
                cel3.value = z[2]
                
                cel4 = ws.cell(y, 36)
                cel4.value = z[3]
                
                cel5 = ws.cell(y, 38)
                cel5.value = z[4]
                
                y += 1


f.close()
wb.save(file1)
```

before i even get to try and error with my loops this error came up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ict\.spyder-py3\test.py", line 178, in <module>
    f = open(file, 'r')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 313, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 94, in _validate_archive
    raise InvalidFileException(msg)

InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support .log file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm
```

I even tried converting log to txt and it still came up the same error.

I look around for quite some time now and still cant find a way to debug this part. It would really help if you have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `open` calls openpyxl's?

How about `from openpyxl import *` to `from openpyxl import load_workbook`.